# Memofy links considered harmful?

Tags: discussion, hyperlinks, spam

I'm seeing more and more answers linking to [memofy](http://www.memofy.com), instead of containing the answer directly.  Is this spam?  I have not created and do not want to create a memofy account, so all I ever see is the login screen.

Example posts:

- [Problem with Video recording after auto focus in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4244999/problem-with-video-recording-after-auto-focus-in-android/4360754#4360754)
- [How do I list / export private keys from a keystore?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/150167/how-do-i-list-export-private-keys-from-a-keystore/3206202#3206202)

And, a [link to search for all URLs matching `http://www.memofy.com/*`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=url%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.memofy.com%2F%2A%22&submit=search)

Comment: Can you add examples to your question?

Comment: In SO I found this 2 answers with links to Memofy: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4244999/problem-with-video-recording-after-auto-focus-in-android/4360754#4360754 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/150167/how-do-i-list-export-private-keys-from-a-keystore/3206202#3206202 Indeed, you need an account to be able to follow the link.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4244999/problem-with-video-recording-after-auto-focus-in-android/4360754#4360754 is an example.

Comment: +1 I agree with you...I'm not signing up either...but the second example at least didn't rely only on the memofy link

Comment: That was the same example...

Comment: Only [6 occurences](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=url%3A%22*memofy.com*%22) isn't exactly an epidemic, but feel free to downvote them, comment, or as Gilles says, flag if the answer doesn't work without the link

Comment: I added a search link; see the syntax at http://stackoverflow.com/search

Comment: @Jeff - Your link isn't working. I tried to fix it but it looks like there may be a bug in the link parsing.

Comment: @bemace yeah it had to be FULLY escaped. I thought CTRL+L did that.. will check

Comment: `I have not created and do not want to create a memofy account, so all I ever see is the login screen.` +1 Very much agree with this. I've never even heard of memofy, but the general consensus is that *all* answers here should be **self-contained**.

Answer (score 17):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4244999/problem-with-video-recording-after-auto-focus-in-android/4360754#4360754) consists of just a link to memofy. Answers containing just a link are strongly frowned upon in the first place (From “[how to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)”: “Provide context for links”). Answers containing just a link to a private site are completely useless.

[image: flag]

The proper response is to flag this as “not an answer”.

For answers that contain useful content in addition to the memofy link, a comment remarking that the memofy link is useless is in order. If the user doesn't respond, it would be reasonable to edit the link out, since it's noise.

Comment: Does the memofy link contain code or something? If so, it might be worth creating a shared account (http://www.bugmenot.com/ ?) and copying-and-pasting the information out of there and directly into the post before removing the link.

Comment: @CodyGray I can't be bothered, but feel free to do it if you like. There's a difficulty with copying information from there: we'd typically not have the right to copy-paste (unless there's an explicit license on whatever is behind that link).

Comment: Oh really? I assumed it was being used as a code sharing site like pastebin or something. In that case, there should be no problem copying the code back into their answer. I guess not...

Comment: @CodyGray Licensing is explicit. By default, only fair use is allowed, and that doesn't permit displaying the material in public.

Comment: Wow, yeah. Then I'm all for banning these altogether... (Yeah, I'm a radical.)

Answer (score 9):

I would say that also in this case it is valid what already said for answers containing just a link: They are not answers. An answer should contain a summary of what reported in the link, to allow those who are reading the answer to decide if they want to follow that link; the other reason the summary should be provided is that link rot happens, and an answer with just a link would not be anymore useful.

If you need to log in to the site for which the link has been provided, then that is a reason more to avoid those links; I don't want to log in another site to read an answer I could read on an SE site.

Answer (score 8):

You've said "more and more answers" but both the answers you linked to were from *last year*.

One was a self-answer to a zero-score question, and the other had four upvoted answers above it.

These answers aren't being upvoted because they're not useful, so they aren't going to become more prevalent.

The reputation system prevents this from becoming a problem.

Edit: And the search query shows four answers with memoify links. I don't know how many have been deleted / edited out, but it confirms this is not a big problem.

Comment: It is hard to believe that I keep running into the same two answers time and again, but perhaps that is what's happening.  I feel like I am seeing memofy a lot.